# How can you use Vue single file components in a normal webapp?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to use the [Vue single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) with the following constraints:

1. I have 3 single file components: the main `App` and 2 subcomponents `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`.
2. I have a normal html page generated by some server side application. Like so:

```html
<html>
<body>
<App>
.. some markup

  <ComponentA />

.. some other markup

  <ComponentB />

</App>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I have [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/) to compile my single file components and instantiate them against the markup in the page without modifying the content of the page aside from, obviously, rendering `<ComponentA/>` and `<ComponentB/>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is either add componentA and componentB as a child component of app.

example:

```
import ComponentA from './componentA.vue';
import ComponentB from './componentB.vue';

export default {
 data () {
  return {
   greeting: 'example'
  }
},
components: {
 componentA: ComponentA,
 componentB, ComponentB
 }
}
```

then in your app.vue html tag

```
<span> example filler text </span>
 <component-a><ComponentA>
<div> example</div>
  <component-a><ComponentB>
```

**OR**

you may want to add componentA and componentB as a child slot in the app component.

See example:
 https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7178